# passing a reference to an array TO a function THAT returns a reference to an array

Tags: c++, arrays, reference, c++14

I basically tried this:

```
#include <iostream>

int(&sort(int(&array)[]))[];
double(&sort(double(&array)[]))[];
char(&sort(char(&array)[]))[];

int main(){
    int array[]{23, 44, 53, 65, 87, 1, 2, 0, 9};

    sort(array);
}

int(&sort(int(&array)[]))[]{
    std::cout<<"Function is entered, just for test"<<std::endl;
}
```

But, the compiler complained, the first thing it complained was that the array was not bound, but, isn't this a one dimensional array? So, I thought that it was possible, the next thing it complained was, that the the call to **sort(array)** didn't match any overloaded function, so I thought that my syntax is incorrect. So, How do I declare a function that accepts a reference to an array that returns a reference to an array?

Comment: What's the point of the exercise? What do you hope to achieve? Why not simply `int* sort(int* array);` ?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik , I know, but it's just a bit of exercise as I'm beginning in C++ , and thought, it should be syntactically possible using references. Is it not possible with the language ?

Comment: [In my test](http://rextester.com/AGBL50565), I don't get anything similar to "array was not bound" error. I do get "no matching function for call" error. That's because `int[9]` (an array of 9 ints) and `int[]` (an array of ints of indeterminate bound) are two distinct, unrelated types.

Comment: `auto& sort(auto& array)` would be simpler

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Function parameters cannot have type "reference to array of unknown bound"

Comment: @M.M The declaration `int(&sort(int(&array)[]))[];` appears to compile though, at least with clang and MSVC. Only GCC complains.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik could be a compiler extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mention the template parameters (or use auto). An array of unknown bound cannot be a function parameter (other than the pointer adjustment case).

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
auto sort( T(&x)[N] ) -> T(&)[N]
{
    return x;
}
```

Note that it is more normal style for an algorithm such as "sort" to receive an iterator pair (or a view); that way the caller can easily decide to sort a subset of the array.

Comment: So there's no syntax for explicit array to reference return then?

Comment: @mathmaniage What do you mean by "explicit array to reference return"? I for one don't understand the question.

Comment: @mathmaniage i'm not sure what you mean - the code in my answer declares the function as returning a reference to array

Comment: @M.M , I didn't see the trailing '->' sorry.

Comment: @M.M , but, what about doing it without a template?

Comment: @M.M , not to be annoying, but just to measure the possibility of the language despite the complexity, is it possible?

Comment: @mathmaniage well anything's possible . You have to pass the array size one way or another. I'm not really sure what you're asking. Your original code is invalid, this code is valid and does what you asked.

Comment: @M.M, Well the straightforward thing I am asking is the code to pass a reference to an array(ok of definite size), that returns a reference to an array WITHOUT ANY POINTERS OR TEMPLATES.

Comment: @mathmaniage You could use a fixed integer instead of template parameter `N` in my code.

Comment: @M.M , below I have posted an answer, but tell me the syntax for the sort function that does the same without using the 'auto' keyword.

Comment: I'm not sure what your line of questioning is about,  it is like "How do I screw in this screw without a screwdriver?"

Comment: You might be learning a wrong language. There's no C++ without templates. Is this an assignment?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
#include <iostream>

auto sort(int(&array)[10])->int(&)[10];

int main(void){
    int array[10]{2, 34, 1, 7, 0, 12, 11, 15, 22, 8};

    sort(array);

    for(auto x: array){
        std::cout<<"The number is: "<<x<<std::endl;
    }

}

auto sort(int(&array)[10])->int(&)[10]{

    for(int i{0}; i< 10; i++){
        for(int j{0}; j < 10; j++){
            if(array[j]> array[i]){
                int temp{array[i]};
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
                }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `array_size` is redundant, it can only ever be 10 anyway

Comment: @M.M. Well, only the demonstration, that's not the main point.

Comment: @M.M, the main point is to do this without the 'auto', 'template' and 'pointers'.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention these mysterious additional requirements. And you could remove `array_size` without affecting those requirements anyway. And your code uses `auto` twice.

Comment: @M.M , I didn't realize people would be using templates, since I just began C++ , and I don't think I used it twice, one is a prototype. And if you know the answer, please append it to your own.